# best way to interact between vue.js and a python script

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, curl

i am wondering what could be the best method to run a python script base on a input in a vue application.
I found that i could make a api with flask that can run the python script of my choice and using a curl request i can call it from the vue application.

Do you have other idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea I can think of is to set up HTTP endpoints in your Flask API and from there call the API directly from your Vue application.

Something like this:
Python script

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return "You data here"
    else:
        body = request.body #access the body you sent on JS below
        <put whatever you want to do here>
```

Javascript

```
const myRequest = async() =>{
    const response = fetch("http://localhost:8000", {
        method: "POST",
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "Application/JSON"}
        body:{<your stuff here>}
        )
}
```